# Implementation of calculation of gamma for RBF SVM

Tags: machine-learning, matlab

I have implemented the calculation of gamma value for RBF SVM as described in Liu et al (2012) [https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6246300]. Here's a snapshot of the example from the paper:

[image: Snapshot showing the calculation of optimal gamma value for RBF SVM]

Here is my implementation in MATLAB:

```
% Let data be a table type variable with 1st column having class label and 
% variables X1 ... Xn from 2nd column onwards

% Split data by class
data_class0 = data{data.Class==0,2:end};
data_class1 = data{data.Class==1,2:end};

% Calculate within class squared Euclidean distances
d_within_class0 = squareform(pdist(data_class0, 'squaredeuclidean'));
d_within_class1 = squareform(pdist(data_class1, 'squaredeuclidean'));

% Calculate between class squared Euclidean distances
d_between_class = pdist2(data_class0, data_class1, 'squaredeuclidean');

% Calculate average W and B values
W = mean([d_within_class0(:); d_within_class1(:)], 'all');
B = mean(d_between_class(:));

% Calculate optimal gamma
if B > W
    gamma = sqrt((B-W)/(4*log(B/W)));
else
    disp('Gamma cannot be calculated as B < W');
end
```

I am looking for feedback on whether or not this implementation is correct and any thing that might need improvement.